# Add new record hangs on WinfForm - and I don't understand why

Tags: c#, winforms

I have inherited a Windows Forms Application.  We are having some performance issues, when trying to save a new record to the SQL Table.  It hangs.

For the most part, I have ruled out the database or Table Structure as the problem.  I don't believe that is the case here.

I am very new to this, and am having trouble stepping through and finding the root of the problem.

The form basics: (Only included what I thought was relevant code, but can add more if needed)

```
public partial class frmBadgeCreate : daBaseForm
{
private boBadger_History oBadger_History;
Form mainFormHandler;
private string whome;
}

public frmBadgeCreate(String cutomItem)
{
InitializeComponent();

if (daAppDesktop.IsRunning)
{
oBadger_History = new boBadger_History();
oBadger_History.GetAll(); ///  This line right here seems to have some importance
whome = customItem;
}
}

public void saveitall() /// Save Action that hangs
{
// listing of form variables to be saved to table columns
var vlast = textbox_H_lname.Text;
var vfirst = textbox_H_fname.Text;
. . .and on and on . . . 

var badger_History = new Badger_History() {hlastname = vlast, vfirstname = vfirst . . . and on and on . . };
oBadger_History.Add(badger_History);
oBadger_History.Save();  /// This is where things just hang forever.
```

Because this is a 'Lone Ranger App' that was handed to me, I am struggling to grasp it.  What really confuses me is that when I comment out the 'oBadger_History.GetAll()' line, the save works very fast!  Instantly.  When I add the line back in, it hangs.  I only know this, because I have spent days commenting out each line, one by one, and testing results.

The oBadger_History.GetAll(); looks like it is somehow used for the auto complete feature, so it is needed.

What has me totally scratching my head is that I can't see the connection between the 'GetAll' and the save. Why would the getAll impact the save function at all?

Here is the GetAll code, if that sheds any light:

```
public daBindingList<Badger_History> GetAll()
{
BadgerContext cn = (BadgerContext)this.context;
List<Badger_History> ents = cn.Badger_History.ToList();
this.EntityList = new daBindingList<Badger_History>(ents);
return this.EntityList;
}
```

Again, I don't believe that the SQL database/tables are the problem, seeing that I can get the save to work properly by removing the one line of code.  I just can't seem to find a way to resolve

Comment: GetAll will load some data into the DbContext (BadgerContext), this sounds like it is loading lots of rows of data from the SQL server.  Save will be looking through these loaded rows for any changes.  If you have thousands or millions of rows, this may take some time to work out what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
List<Badger_History> ents = cn.Badger_History.ToList();
```

Will load EVERY row in the `Badger_History` table into memory.  *How many records are in this table?*

If there are lots of rows, then when you call `Save();` (which I assume is some sort of wrapper around SaveChanges(), then EF will look through every row for anything that has changed.  In your case, there may be 0 rows changed, as all you are interested in, is the row you are adding.

To speed things, you could change loading the data into a 'non-tracking' query

```
List<Badger_History> ents = cn.Badger_History.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

This will still load in all the records, but they will no longer be counted when trying to save.

Comment: There are just over 12k records in the table.  I have made the change to a non tracking query, as suggested.  This helped out a lot.  But still hangs some.  Previously it would hang for minutes on end, until I would cancel it out.  Now, the save happens in 20 seconds.  Which is a huge increase, but still not appropriate.  I must be missing something more here.

Comment: Let me also clarify:  This form is for data entry.  It adds a new record to the SQL Table.   That said, I noticed it has an 'ADD' and 'SAVE' call.  oBadger_History.Add(badger_History);
oBadger_History.Save();   I don't understand why it needs the .SAVE() for an insert.  Wouldn't that be just the .ADD() ??   When I remove the SAVE, the new record is NOT added to the Table, using just ADD().  It needs both?  I am out of my comfort zone, but that seems odd for an insert?

Comment: I was able to finally resolve it. I had to create a new instance of boBadger_History (boBadger_History oSaveit = new boBadgerHistory(); circumventing the 'GetByAll' and then the Add and Save() work perfectly and instantly.  I REALLY appreciate all of your help.  It was through your responses that put me on the path of looking at things from the bo perspective.  WinForms is way out of my scope and that is the real issue, for me.  Thank You !!!

Comment: For future reference, with entity framework, calling Add just adds it to the in-memory 'list of entities EF knows about', it's not until you call SaveChanges that it's actually sent to the SQL server.

Comment: Generally, you would create an new context for each 'unit of work', so if you want to save, say, 10 different entities, you would create a new context, add or update each entity, and then call SaveChanges, and only then will EF work out what needs to be sent to the database to persist those changes (which in the case of some updates, may not trigger an UPDATE as no changes were detected).  This is more efficient than every time you call Add, it writes to the database.